# Visual Studio 2013 (Productivity Power Tools) - Colorized Parameter Help: how to set text color in Intellisense

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, productivity-power-tools

I have a problem with "Colorized Parameter Help" function in PPT 2013.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace/view/Discussions
Other features -> no. 13

I can't find how to change text color of Intellisense tooltip(?)

I have dark scheme but when I change "Signature Help - Text" to white there is no change in intellisense (still black text color)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last! after hours of searching...
Here it is the setting:
[image]